The STM32L010F4P6 does not work when configured with the internal MSI clock at 32.768kHz
I have a simple program where I am testing the internal clock of the STM32L010F4P6. I need to configure it to 32.768kHz due to power consumption requirements, as I need it to consume as little as possible. I configure the clock using MSI with SYSCLK=65.536kHz and AHB prescaler=2 to have an HCLK=32.768kHz. I also configure pin PA10 as an output to turn an LED on or off. In the main loop, I toggle the LED with a 100ms delay. I compile and run the program, but the result is that the LED does not change, i.e., it does not blink. However, if I change the AHB prescaler to 1 to have an HCLK=65.536kHz, compile and run, the LED blinks. This happens when I configure all the internal clocks and lower HCLK to 32.768kHz; the LED does not work. However, when I increase HCLK to 65.536kHz, the LED works. What could be happening? I have conducted many tests and have been trying to understand this behavior for some time.

/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "main.h"

/* Private includes ----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */

/* USER CODE END Includes */

/* Private typedef -----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PTD */

/* USER CODE END PTD */

/* Private define ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PD */
/* USER CODE END PD */

/* Private macro -------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PM */

/* USER CODE END PM */

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/

/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */

/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);

/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */

/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* Private user code ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */

/* USER CODE END 0 */

/**
  * @brief  The application entry point.
  * @retval int
  */
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
 
  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */

  //  SysTick_Config(SystemCoreClock/1000);
  while (1)
  {
      HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOA,Led_Pin);
      HAL_Delay(100);
     

    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}


void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};

  /** Configure the main internal regulator output voltage
  */
  __HAL_PWR_VOLTAGESCALING_CONFIG(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE2);

  /** Initializes the RCC Oscillators according to the specified parameters
  * in the RCC_OscInitTypeDef structure.
  */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI|RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_MSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_DIV4;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSICalibrationValue = RCC_HSICALIBRATION_DEFAULT;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.MSIState = RCC_MSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.MSICalibrationValue = 16;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.MSIClockRange = RCC_MSIRANGE_0;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_NONE;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB buses clocks
  */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_MSI;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV16;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV16;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_0) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}


static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
  
  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA,Led_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : Pin Led_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = Led_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);


}


I conducted tests with the different internal clocks because I don't have an external clock, and I don't have a pin available to place an external clock. The problem is that when I configure it to 32.768kHz and test to make the LED blink with a 100ms delay, the LED does not blink. However, when I increase the clock to 65.536kHz, the LED works and blinks.

cross post https://community.st.com/t5/stm32cubemx-mcus/stm32l010f4p6-not-work-with-msi-clock-32-768khz/td-p/670558

Running your clock so slow seems like a bad idea. Run it as fast as it can go but make sure you enter sleep mode when there's nothing to do. The clock speed is 0 in sleep mode, and running as fast as possible the rest of the time means you get to sleep mode quicker.

Cube uses a 1ms SysTick interrupt (that's the source of timing for example of the HAL_Delay(), too). At 32kHz system clock, there are only 32 machine cycles to execute that interrupt, and execution of that interrupt probably lasts more than 32 machine cycles.
In other words, your program probably chains forever SysTick interrupts.
Solution is not to use Cube. Cube is good for "usual" work, and your case is unusual.

Ok, I also have Keil uVision and STM32CubeMX installed. In that case, can it be configured with CubeMX and create a project for Keil using HAL? Or is the problem with the HAL libraries?

The toolchain is not the problem. I'll guess wek meant that the STM32 HAL (which uses SysTick) might be the problem. Either way, running your system at kilohertz frequency is a bad idea. Run the CPU as fast as it can go, and sleep whenever you can.
